# firefox css columns breaks - does it work?

Tags: firefox, css

Firefox 14.

I'm trying to use css props:

```
-moz-column-break-before:always;
-moz-column-break-after: always;
```

But it does not work as it works in chrome: (`-webkit-column-break-before: always;`)

Are column breaks in FF broken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not "broken," rather not implemented. There is no such property listed on [their exentions reference page](https://developer-new.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions).

Webkit has it, but even that is considered "Proprietary WebKit-prefixed properties (**do not use on Web sites**)" according to [this page](https://developer-new.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference/Webkit_Extensions#Proprietary_WebKit-prefixed_properties_%28do_not_use_on_Web_sites%29) (as of 7-30-2012).